# Best Ways to process bulk records in Delphi7

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, delphi, sql-server-2012

I am working with Delphi7 and SQL Server 2012 and facing an issue where need to process bulk data(~5-7GB) from DBNew and DBOld to generate a combined output.

Looking for an option in delphi7 so that it will be easy to join records of DBNew with DBOld. Like DataSet component exists in .net.

Looking for an option in Delphi7 where data handling in program will become easy and fast.

Edit:
What about TClientDataset, I found it [in-memory database-independent dataset](https://www.thoughtco.com/using-the-tclientdataset-in-delphi-applications-1058369). Does it provides a set of records independent of any database and I can use it for Joins with OldDB?

Comment: Well, 5-7GB is a huge amount of data to be processed on the client side. I would write a stored procedure that would join the tables (using linked server) and output store in a temporary table (with output I mean resultset that is possible to process by the human, not hundreds of thousands of rows). Only such output I would fetch to the client to display (build report or whatsoever).

Comment: @Victoria - Thanks for quick response, I hope my question is little clear after editing. It would not be possible to create Linked server in our case, as our team don't want that maintenance so I am out of luck on that

Comment: If you want to process 5-7GB of data on the client side, you will always pay performance costs. Btw. what do you mean by combined output? Aggregate functions, join? I'm asking because because there is no universal advice for that. For example, if you were about to calculate average value of a column from two databases, you could fetch only one value from each whilst the calculation would happen on server. What is the output of that combining, where it goes, is it presented to the user somehow?

Comment: I would need to join records of both databases to get respective information available in Old Db, it will definitely reduce the volume but still it would not be less then 2.5 to 3 GB. It is kind of search results, we ship at clients end(into there respective DataBase on there request), they choose there records to get into the system, which is then represented into reports. This utility is a part of process which is being executed at Our DataBase server  over night.

Comment: Read more about bcp utility (Bcp.exe)

Comment: I'm not aware of any component that would be able to work with more than one connection (for inner join from multiple databases) in Delphi. I'm afraid you'll need to build a memory dataset which is a performance hell with such amount of data. Nothing compares to a linked server and server side processing (by a stored procedure for example).

Comment: "What about TClientDataset" Problem is, the CDS hits a brick wall, performance wise, when handling more than a few tens of thousand rows. If you can't use the linked server@Victoria suggested, consider the BCP suggestion.  You could write a Delphi utility to use BCP to export one of the datasets to text, zip it up, copy it to the other server, import it there and do your process on that server.